# Variadic templates with 'const' parameter overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, variadic-templates

Reduced sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void func(T &x)
{
    std::cout << "non-const " << x << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void func(const T &x)
{
    std::cout << "const " << x << std::endl;
}

template<typename ...ARGS>
void proxy(ARGS ...args)
{
    func(args...);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 3;

    func(i);
    func(5);
    func("blah");

    proxy(i);
    proxy(5);
    proxy("blah");
}
```

Expected output:

```
non-const 3
const 5
const blah
non-const 3
const 5
const blah
```

Actual output:

```
non-const 3
const 5
const blah
non-const 3
non-const 5
non-const blah
```

So somehow the `const` qualifier of the function parameter gets lost when put through the variadic template. Why? How can I prevent this?

PS: tested with GCC 4.5.1 and [SUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux_distributions) 11.4

Comment: It has nothing to do with variadic templates. Your function template proxy's parameters are non-references, so the const of the function arguments is ignored when deducing the template arguments.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just stumble upon the [forwarding problem](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm). This issue is solved using [perfect forwarding](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_07.html).

Basically, you need to take your parameters by rvalue-reference, and rely on [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to correctly forward them while keeping their nature:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void proxy(Args&& ...args)  
{
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Don't you need `std::forward<Args...>`?

Comment: @juanchopanza No. That would pass all the type arguments to `std::forward`, but `std::forward` has only one type argument.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Right, forward also takes only one parameter, so I guess we need `func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` or something like that? the sample in the answer doesn't compile on my gcc4.7 snapshot.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yeah, you're right. I tried to fix it and forgot about `args`. Ooops.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Thanks for the correction! I had tried the code I gave initially, but it worked only by accident: the sample code in the question uses a single argument :).

Answer (score 6):

As Luc already mentioned this is a problem of forwarding and the answer to *how to prevent it* is to use *perfect forwarding*. But I will try to address the other questions at the end:

> So somehow the const qualifier of the function parameter gets lost when put through the variadic template. Why?

This has everything to do with type inference. Ignore that you are using variadic templates and consider the simplest one argument template:

```
template <typename T>
void one_arg_proxy( T arg ) {
   func( arg );
}
```

At the place of call you have `one_arg_proxy( 5 )`, that is, the argument is an `int` *rvalue*. Type inference kicks in to figure out what the type `T` should be, and the rules dictate that `T` is `int`, so the call gets translated to `one_arg_proxy<int>(5)` and the instantiation of the template that gets compiled is:

```
template <>
void one_arg_proxy<int>( int arg ) {
   func( arg );
}
```

Now the call to `func` takes an *lvalue* argument, and thus the version of `func` taking a non-const reference is a better match (no conversions required) than the one taking a `const&`, yielding the result that you are getting. The issue here is that `func` does not get called with the argument to `proxy`, but rather with the internal copy that `proxy` made of it.